# How to create similarity matrix between words using w2v

Tags: python, matrix, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I created training data using word2vec.

I used 'wv.similarity' to find the cosine similarity between word1 and word2.

I want to find the cosine similarity between all words(like a correlation table) in a list, but I don't know how.

[word1, word2, word3, word4, ........]

Please help me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each word has some id. Use a double for loop over the ids. And calculate the cos-similarity.

```
table[id1][id2]=cos-sim(word1,word2)
```